# Optimize my "capture" algorithm for my Java checkered-type board game

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, matrix

- checkered board game is a 11x11 matrix.
- pieces are white, black, (1)whiteking
- can "capture" a piece by sandwiching opponent

  - ex) a black piece has a white piece/white king to its left and right or top and bottom
- can also sandwich and capture using the edge of the board or any of the 4 corner pieces

  - ex) white piece on the left edge of board, and then black piece moves directly to the right of the white piece, that would be a capture

so far i have a

- 11 x 11 matrix
- (int) 0 = empty, 1 = white, 2 = black, 3 = whiteking

so my algorithm so far is the basic, check top/bottom/left/right, if it's the opposition, then check if the piece next to that again is a friendly piece, if so, then capture.

but then i can't just do it that simply, because if the piece is on the 2 outter edge rows or columns, using that above algorithm i'll get an ArrayOutofBoundsException error.

then i have a huge if-statement for if the piece is White or Black.

i just feel like there's an easier way to optimize this.. and as a beginning programmer, I can't see it.  can someone maybe suggest something?

if you look at my code below.. you can see this is ONLY if the move is in the outer edges... then i gotta pretty much re-copy and paste all that if it's in the "1" column/row... THEN i can finally check 2 spaces up/left/right/down without having to worry about the ArrayOutofBoundsException.

THEN i have to do all that again for Black Pieces..my code is just looking really sloppy and i feel there's an easier way of doing this.  Any suggestions?

```
void makeMove(int typePiece, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
    board[toRow][toCol] = board[fromRow][fromCol];
    board[fromRow][fromCol] = EMPTY;        

    //CAPTURE
    if(typePiece == WHITE) {
        if(toRow==0) { //top row
            //check right
            if(toCol!=9 && board[toRow][toCol+1]==BLACK && 
                    (toCol==10 || board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol+1]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check left
            if(toCol!=1 && board[toRow][toCol-1]==BLACK && 
                    (toCol==0 || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol-1]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check bottom
            if(board[toRow-1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow-1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
        }
        else if(toRow == 10) { //bottom row
            //check right
            if(toCol!=9 && board[toRow][toCol+1]==BLACK && (toCol==10 || board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol+1]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check left
            if(toCol!=1 && board[toRow][toCol-1]==BLACK && (toCol==0 || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol-1]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check top
            if(board[toRow+1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow+1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
        }
        else if(toCol == 0) { //left column
            //check right
            if(board[toRow][toCol+1]==BLACK && (board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol+2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol+1]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check top
            if(toRow!=1 && board[toRow+1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow+1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check bottom
            if(toRow != 9 && board[toRow-1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow-1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
        }
        else if(toCol == 10) { //right column
            //check left
            if(board[toRow][toCol-1]==BLACK && (toCol==0 || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITE || board[toRow][toCol-2]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow][toCol-1]=EMPTY;
            //check top
            if(toRow!=1 && board[toRow+1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow+2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow+1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
            //check bottom
            if(toRow != 9 && board[toRow-1][toCol]==BLACK && (board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITE || board[toRow-2][toCol]==WHITEKING)) {
                board[toRow-1][toCol]=EMPTY;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is more fit for Code Review site. Anyway, you can store the offset from the current cell in an array and loop through it.

Comment: oh sorry, i've always used this site whenever i had a programming question

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by "store the offset from the current cell in an array and loop through it"?  maybe provide a simple example?

Comment: Not your code, but if, for example, I want to move a King in chess, then I can store `offsetX[] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}` and `offsetY[] = {-1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1}` (same index is in the same pair of offset). Then I will just loop through the array and calculate the new position based on the current position and the offset stored.

Comment: =(  i'm not really understanding what the offset and 0's, 1's, and -1's are supposed to mean and how they correlate with each other and how they correlate with moving..  i'm so sorry think you can elaborate on that one more time?  if i understand what you're trying to tell me, i think it'll help me tremendously

Comment: i pretty much see 2 arrays filled with those 0's, 1's, and -1's.. i just don't see an example of a Chess King and how it can move using those 2 arrays given?

Comment: The array stores all the moves that the King can make from (X, Y). If the board is numbered from **top left corner**, the directions are up (X, Y -1) (1st element in each array), down (X, Y + 1), right-up (X + 1, Y - 1), right (X + 1, Y), right-down(X + 1, Y + 1), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that a piece can be captured only as the result of the movement of another piece.  Say that you have a white piece that moves to some spot adjacent to a black piece (eight checks of "is there a black piece next to me"?); at that point, check if there is a white piece across from it along the same line (if the black piece is below the first white piece, check for another white piece directly below the first black piece; if the black piece is diagonally up and to the right, check for another white piece up and to the right of the black piece; etc.).  Also, you'd need to check every time a piece moved for a) is there an enemy piece around me, and if so b) is it mirrored on the other side by another enemy piece?

Try something along these lines:

```
for all eight directions (up, down, left, right, and the four diagonals):
    is there an enemy piece in that direction adjacent to me?
    if so:
        is there a friendly piece in that direction that is also adjacent to that enemy piece?
        if so:
             remove that piece
```

and

```
for all eight directions:
    is there an enemy piece in that direction adjacent to me?
    if so:
         is there another enemy piece in the opposite direction that is also adjacent to me?
    if so:
         remove me
```

Comment: hey cosmic, tyvm for the reply and the psuedo-code.  looks good to me, but my main concern is the ArrayOutofBoundsException exception.

Comment: whoops didn't mean to send that.

for example, let's say i have a piece on the left edge, the 0 column.  if i run that method and it checks to the left of that piece, i will get that ArrayOutofBoundsException exception...

any ideas how I don't have to worry about that?

Comment: Ah, in that case you just need to add another check "is the index of the position I'm looking at less than zero or greater than the maximum? if so: don't check it".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seem very similar to the "Go" game.

What you could do is to check what is called in go "liberties".
A liberty is a free place next to a group of pieces. If a group has no more liberties (surrounded by the opponent) then the group dies.

Here are some hints on how you can implement that.

When a piece is moved, you check its neighbours. If one of the neighbours is an opponent,

```
function: hasPieceLiberty(Position piece): return true if one of the neighbours is empty

function: hasGroupLiberty(Position currentPiece):
   add current piece to visited pieces for this group
   if currentPiece.hasPieceLiberty -> return true
   else 
       if currentPiece has no more non visited neighbours for this group -> return false
       else call hasGroupLiberty for non visited neighbours in the group

function: move(Position piece)
   if piece has neighbours that are opponents, check if opponent group has liberties
```

I hope that helps

Edit: I notice that your problem is actually simpler that what I thought in the first place. I thought that you had to surround the opponent everywhere, not simply to sides of a line. Then you should check CosmicComputer's proposal

Comment: hey antoine, thanks for the reply and algorithm.  that helps alot.

right now my main concern is the ArrayOutofBoundsException exception.. say i were to run that algorithm on a piece on the left edge... if i were to check to the left of that piece, i would get that arrayoutofboundsexception, do you know any way i can get around this?  ty regardless

Comment: As suggested by CosmicComputer you need to add checks before calling the function that will check the capture:
am I on the left side; am I at the top, am I at the bottom, am i on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

A few custom items helped to clean up the code when I was trying to solve this:

`struct`**`Point`** takes an 'x' and a 'y'.  Handy for mapping out the contents of a 2d array.
`Operations` can include **adding**, subtracting, etc, that operate, separately, on the 'x' and 'y' values.
An **`isValid`** check could be useful for determining if the point is a valid index of an array (given the array, as a parameter).  Overriding **`ToString()`** is also nice.

An array of Points that holds all the desired **directions** from a source Point, (`dir4`, `dir8`, etc) is great for checking what is around it.  Iterate through the provided directions: [`foreach( Point dir in dir4 ){ testPoint = sourcePoint + dir; ... }`].  Use `isValid` to determine if the Point is outside the array before attempting to check the position's contents to avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.